# PHP Design pattern to pass a class name and check it for the class existence

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have several classes handling data validation and API requests preparation for every external API function. An example of those:

```
class PostProductFunction($user_params)
{
  validate()
  {
    //...
  }
  invoke($user_params)
  {
    $this->validate();
    //doing request...
  }
}
```

I have an APIAccount class to represent one of several API accounts. It handles auth and it has a method

```
function invokeFunction($functionClassName, $user_params)
{
  // check if the class $functionClassName exists and creates an instance of it
  // ... $obj = new $functionClassName();
  $obj->invoke($user_params);

}
```

So, the function class doesn't know about auth stuff and the APIAccount class doesn't know about user data structure.

The question is how to handle this $functionClassName inside the APIAccount class. Do I need to store all names of function classes somewhere? Do I need some kind of enum class? I don't want to simply take a string and then check whether the class with this name exists because the programmer passing this string can easily mistype, and in general he needs documentation to know the proper function name. I want that he somehow see all available options with something like enum. Do you have any ideas how to better implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to both keep the invocation method signature and make it easier for programmers to see the hint with possible class names to pass in IDE.
The method itself remains as it is:

```
function invokeFunction($functionClassName, $user_params)
{
  // check if the class $functionClassName exists and creates an instance of it
  if (! class_exists($functionClassName)) {
    throw new Exception("Class {$functionClassName} does not exist.");
  }
  $obj = new $functionClassName();
  $obj->invoke($user_params);
}
```

However, in the classes which names can be passed as $functionClassName one needs to add a static method like this:

```
public static function getFunctionName()
{
   $function_name = get_called_class();
  // .... some optional operations with the name depending on what part of
  // (or the full name) invokeFunction is anticipating
  return $function_name
}
```

Then calling the invokeFunction is as simple as:

```
invokeFunction (SomeCertainFunctionClass::getFunctionName(), array('some_param'=>'some_val'));
```

Using this approach you can have your IDE hint when typing 'SomeCertainFunctionClass' and at the same time you can use a class name string as a function argument without any downfalls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need a design pattern for this. The following should satisfy your needs:

```
function invokeFunction($functionClassName, $user_params)
{
    if (! class_exists($functionClassName)) {
        throw new Exception("Class {$functionClassName} does not exist.");
    }
    $obj = new {$functionClassName}();
    $obj->invoke($user_params);
}
```

Comment: yes, this is the solution I've already mentioned in my question. The downfall is that this invokeFunction is not very comfortable to deal with. If you call it like InvokeFunction ('PostProductFunction', $someParams) ; then you must keep in mind that there is a class PostProductFunction in advance. If you use an IDE, it cannot help you with hints, it's easy to make a typo,and it's hard for other programmers to know what kind of strind they should pass, whether it should be the classname or some part of it,or some key in some array, or something else. Maybe there's a way to make it more pleasant